# generate and download csv file by passing parameters to controller method in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv

I have a method GenerateCSV(string accountNumber, string dt1, string dt2) in my ReportController

How do i initiate this request from my Report.cshtml?

```
 <h2>Settled Report</h2><br />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Report", "ReportController", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Accounts: @Html.DropDownList("accountNumber")
            Start Date: @Html.TextBox("dt1", null, new { @class = "date-picker" })
            End Date: @Html.TextBox("dt2", null, new { @class = "date-picker" })
            @*@Html.Hidden("reportType", 1)*@
            <input type="hidden" id="" value="1" name="reportType" />
            <input type="submit" value="View Report" />
        </p>
        <div class="exportbuttons">
            @Html.ActionLink("Export to CSV", "GenerateCSV")
        </div>
    }
```

The *GenerateCSV* is called but all params are null, and the server tries to navigate to *Report/GenerateCSV*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ActionLink` is just a link.  It won't invoke the `GenerateCSV` action with the parameters you want because it is just a link with no parameters being passed.

**UPDATE**
I'm not sure what the intent of your page is:

Is the intent that the user has two buttons, one to view the report, one to export?  If so, refer to Option 2 below.

Is the intent that the user has one button and all it does is export to CSV?  If so, refer to Option 1 below.

**Option 1 - Only one button on the page**

Change your Razor as follows:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateCSV", "Report", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Accounts: @Html.DropDownList("accountNumber")
            Start Date: @Html.TextBox("dt1", null, new { @class = "date-picker" })
            End Date: @Html.TextBox("dt2", null, new { @class = "date-picker" })
            @*@Html.Hidden("reportType", 1)*@
            <input type="hidden" id="" value="1" name="reportType" />
            <input name="reportType" type="submit" value="Export to CSV" />
        </p>
    }
```

**Option 2 - Two buttons on the page**

If you want to allow the user to either click the `View Report` button to view it in a browser or `Export to CSV` to have the report exported instead of shown to the user, I would suggest:

**Change your `Report()` method** so that it accepts a string parameter called `reportType`, and check the value to determine whether to show it in a browser or call `GenerateCSV()`

```
public ActionResult Report(string accountNumber, string dt1, string dt2, string reportType)
{
   if (reportType == "View Report")
   {
      // code to show report to user in browser
   }
   else 
   {
      return GenerateCSV(accountNumber, dt1, dt2);
   }
}
```

**Change your razor as follows:**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Report", "ReportController", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Accounts: @Html.DropDownList("accountNumber")
            Start Date: @Html.TextBox("dt1", null, new { @class = "date-picker" })
            End Date: @Html.TextBox("dt2", null, new { @class = "date-picker" })
            @*@Html.Hidden("reportType", 1)*@
            <input type="hidden" id="" value="1" name="reportType" />
            <input name="reportType" type="submit" value="View Report" />
            <input name="reportType" type="submit" value="Export to CSV" />
        </p>
    }
```

Comment: i need to return the CSV file for the user to download.

Comment: So the only button on the page should be the one to export the CSV?

Comment: Updated with two options - original code I posted and an option if you just need one button on the page that just exports CSV.  In that case, your BeginForm statement needs to be updated to point to the right action.

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be like

```
public class CSVDetails
{
    public List<long> AccountNumber {get; set;}
    public DateTime dt1 {get; set;}
    public DateTime dt2 {get; set;}
}
```

Then your view should be like

```
@model YourProjectNamespace.Models.CSVDetails
<h2>Settled Report</h2><br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Report", "ReportController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Accounts: @Html.DropDownListFor(a=>a.AccountNumber)
        Start Date: @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.dt1, new { @class = "date-picker" })
        End Date: @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.dt2, new { @class = "date-picker" })

        <input type="hidden" id="" value="1" name="reportType" />
        <input type="submit" value="View Report" />
    </p>
    <div class="exportbuttons">
        @Html.ActionLink("Export to CSV", "GenerateCSV")
    </div>
```

In controller

```
public ActionResult GenerateCSV(CSVDetais csv)
{
      // your logic here
}
```

Hope it helps you!!!